# Pass password to su command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have an issue in ubuntu, I want to run command as another user in a bash script without using my own password.
I'm trying

```
echo "password" | su otheruser -c "ls"
```

It results in message

> su: must be run from a terminal

I can't use "sudo -S" as it uses my own password which I don't want to put in a script, the other user is artificial and password doesn't matter. What's more using

```
sudo passwd -d otheruser
```

Doesn't stop anything from asking for password which shouldn't exist.

Comment: This seems to belong on SuperUser, but the current description of SuperUser in the close question dialog has little resemblance to the type of questions currently on SuperUser....so I'm not really sure where the question belongs.

Comment: You can configure sudo to not ask for a password with visudo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be like @Roman Sailopal wrote in his comment.
Add this user to "/etc/sudoers" file using "**visudo**" command and set
"**Your_username    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL**"

Comment: But is there another possibility? To keep sudo command untouched?